# Finding Mail (32-bit) in the start menu

Tags: microsoft-outlook, start-menu, control-panel

I find myself often visiting the Mail control panel for people I'm helping who use Outlook.

However, it never, ever shows up in the start menu for anyones computer:

[image]

Is there some magic string I can type in to get that menu item? I've tried all the obvious ones:

- Mail
- Mail (32-bit)
- Mail 32 Bit

But to no avail. Normally I just go the long way, but with Windows 8 and Metro I'm concerned I'm going to get very frustrated trying to talk users through it over the phone.

Comment: Have you installed the MS Outlook and configure the profile for the mails? Because I am seeing it in my start menu as well in control panel.

Comment: As I am seeing you have configure the Outlook but it does not showing the option there. But I can see very easily it in my start menu as well in control panel. May be its an operating system problem..

Comment: @avirk - I have had this problem on every computer I've worked on for the last 2-3 years. The only thing I can think of is that these are all 64-bit editions; maybe yours is 32-bit?

Comment: Hmmm you are right about this mine is 32-bit. Then probably there should be a path to set for showing it in start menu.

Comment: [Works perfectly fine for me.](http://imgur.com/4QBSqRB) (Win 7 x64) There may be options available to rebuild your search index.

Comment: @DanielB - yours has a different label - it is labelled (Microsoft Outlook 2013). I don't have any Office 2013 machines to test it with, but maybe they've fixed this in later versions. I've had this mail problem on every computer I've ever had, so I don't think it's a search index problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't bother this is not a problem of your system its due to the 64-bit version of Windows and you have the 32-bit version of Outlook. For appearing it in the start menu you have to install the 64-bit version on your system and then you will able to see the `Mail` option when you type it in search. [Here](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/123) is the first link where i got notice to read it that what is the issue with it and [where is mail icon?](http://www.outlook-tips.net/beginner-user/find-mail-icon/) is another thread which helped me to find this. Read both article carefully and then try to install the 64-bit version of MS Office and check that the problem is resolved or not?
I think [add recycle bin to start menu](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/13105/add-the-recycle-bin-to-start-menu-in-windows-7/) article will help you to add **mail** in start menu.
Another way in my mind to `customize` the start menu. For this right click on the **taskbar** and select the **properties** and then select the **Start Menu** tab and select the option for **control panel** `Display as menu` by default it is `Display as link`.   This is a tweak to find it fast I don't know will it be able to pin it in the search option or not? Hope this will help you, best of luck.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would share this, I know this is an old string. A client that I'm not the engineer for called and need help. They have thin-clients for their contractors to check email and use other office products and the like.  I had to reset the profile to stop the explorer from crashing and restarting. The HR person then took over and tried to setup Outlook, but did not do it correctly.  The profile would not open correctly due to an apparent typo.  Unfortunately, the session is completely locked down. You can't even open the start menu.  My solution ended up being to open the task manager and run outlook.exe /profiles from the "run new task" option under files.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's a website that has some good information about this here:
http://www.geekgirls.com/windowsxp_controlpanel.htm

The methods mentioned work for Win7 as well as XP. Essentially, look in the Windows/system32 folder for any *.cpl files. These are the control panel items. Then you just call the one that you want.

For example, if you want to open the Screen Resolution:

```
  Windows + R     (opens Run dialog box)
  control desk.cpl
```

I'm guessing there is a mail.cpl on your computer (mine doesn't have it)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is part of the default start menu program entries. I always circumvent oddities of the start menu by letting users directly execute the startup command line through the *execute* dialog (best way to get there is to use the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keystroke as the "Execute" menu item is disabled in some variants of the Start Menu). In the case of *Mail (32-Bit)* this would be `control mlcfg32.cpl`

`mlcfg32.cpl` is located in your Office installation path, so typically `%PROGRAMFILES%\Microsoft Office\Office <Version>` and this one is inserted into the system-wide `%PATH%` upon installation, so unless the `%PATH%` is being messed with, it should work out of the box. If not, you still can navigate to the office folder and run it from there. As the control panel has become a real mess lately - nearly impossible to navigate anyone through on the phone - even navigating through the folders presents a more coherent user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the Mail (32-bit) item in the Control Panel, then hit Create shortcut. That should place a shortcut on your desktop.

Next, rename the shortcut to be something you want without the pointless "shortcut" ending.

Now, to get it into Start, right click on the shortcut on your desktop and choose Cut (or just press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> shortcut).

Then, go to Start and type in the search box `%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Once you're in that folder, you can right click somewhere empty and hit paste or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Now, a) it will appear when you search whatever you titled the shortcut, and b) it will appear when you go to All Apps. If you want you can also pin it to Start by right clicking the shortcut in All Apps and choosing Pin to Start.